# PBJVideoPlayer not playing video when goes to buffering state in tv os

Tags: ios, objective-c, television

I am using PBJVideoPlayer in tv os Library for Play Youtube Videos. I have set all delegate methods but sometime when video player goes to Delayed state then never come up from that state.

Is this possible in iOS which i looking for?

Please suggest me, how can i do it with alternative ways?